# CMake - VS 2013 compile check fails inside Docker container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2013, cmake

I am trying to compile software using VS 2013 with CMake 3.12.3 inside a
Docker container. I encountered this issue when I try to configure projects:

```
The C++ compiler

"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir:
C:/workspace/_Sandbox_BUILD/libwcrypt/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/MSBuild.exe"
"cmTC_aa4a8.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0"
    Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.30723.0
    [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
    Switch: cmTC_aa4a8.vcxproj


  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
```

It complains about cmTC_aa4a8.vcxproj this files. I saw that on the
filesystem it gets generated cmTC_aa4a8.vcxproj.tmp instead. Running this on
the host machine works as expected and I can see cmTC_aa4a8.vcxproj on the
filesystem.

Inside C:\workspace_Sandbox_BUILD\libwcrypt\build\CMakeFiles\3.12.2\CompilerIdCXX ,
I can see that this project was built successfully. The binary
CompilerIdCXX.exe is there. Only the simple test program fails.

What could be the issue here? What CMake file from C:\Program
Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.12\Modules could be responsible for creating
cmTC_aa4a8.vcxproj ?